# Rails, after_create gets called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever a new user gets created, the user gets a role applied to. This happens via an after_create method. Here is the method:

```
def add_user_role
  self.roles << Role.find_by_role("user")
end
```

However, the user gets the role twice. After the creation, this happens:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Role id: 21, role: "user", created_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44", updated_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44">, #<Role id: 21, role: "user", created_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44", updated_at: "2016-10-27 15:13:44">]>
irb(main):002:0>
```

If I comment out the add command, no role is applied to the user:

```
def add_user_role
 # self.roles << Role.find_by_role("user")
end
```

After the creation:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Has anyone an idea, why this is happenening?

The after_create method is located in User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :add_user_role
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :directions
  has_many :roles, through: :directions



end

private
def add_user_role
  self.roles << Role.find_by_role("user")
end
```

I have two User-Controllers, here they are:

User Controller for the admin:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :current_user_allowed?



    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end


    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      role = params[:role]
      add_user_role(@user,role)

      redirect_to root_path

    end
end

private

def current_user_allowed?
  current_user.roles.each do |role|
    if role.role == "superadmin"
      return
    end
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end

def add_user_role(user, role1)
  user.roles.create(role: role1)
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:role)
end
```

Controller from devise:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
   #def create
    # super
   #end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
   #def update
    # super
   #end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end


end
```

Comment: why is your `add_user_role ` in you `User` model outside of the class definition ?, I see it after the `end` that closes the class.

Comment: @fanta I don't know, I saw, how other people are doing that. But, whether it is in or outside the class, I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: it must be inside your class. Would you mind updating your post with the definition of `ApplicationRecord ` ?, what is that class ?, you might have something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right here where you have two things doing the same role create.

In users_controller:

```
def add_user_role(user, role1)
  user.roles.create(role: role1)
end
```

And then in user.rb:

```
after_create :add_user_role
```

I'd suggest letting the controller handle this and avoid any modifications of the model within the `user.rb` class.

Comment: They are two different methods. One takes two arguments and is only used in update, the other one does not take any arguments and is called after create. As far as I know, create and update are two different operations. I changed the name of my user.rb to add_default_user_role but I have still the same error. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies, to better debug, do you mind writing a `create` action within the controller and moving the `after_create` filter to a method within the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback `after_create :add_user_role` must be defined AFTER the associations

```
# First: 
has_many :directions
has_many :roles, through: :directions

# Then:
after_create :add_user_role
```